# Why is the default action to keep your current version when a package maintainer ships an updated version of a configuration file?

Tags: apt, update

It seems to me that if the package maintainer has shipped an updated configuration file, but you choose to keep your current version, you won't receive any possibly-important changes in the updated file. Why is the default action to keep your current version instead of taking the new one and applying your changes to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you be annoyed if local customization to your configuration were reverted every few months? Also, what software must throw out old configs to make changes? Stable software allows a graceful transition, by introducing new options and changing default behaviors.

You may [configure dpkg](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.package-meta-information.html#sidebar.questions-conffiles) to always use the new configs. Append to /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local

```
DPkg::options { "--force-confdef"; "--force-confnew"; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I'm confused by how I could update for several years while choosing to keep my local config files. I don't understand how the same apache.conf file, for example, doesn't need to be adjusted by the package maintainer during those years as changes are made by them. I understand "local" config files, like with e.g. fail2ban, but the actual apach.conf file seems more "global" and would seem to need updating at some point. I'll research "graceful transition" and related concepts, as I suppose I'm missing something more fundamental in the software development process.

Comment: Sure, the administrator should be reviewing configuration occasionally as fixes and features are rolled out. However, breaking changes in configs do not happen as often as new builds of the package. The semantics of httpd 2.4 configs haven't changed much since 2012.

Comment: Okay, that totally makes sense. I've been involved with this stuff since ~2016, so it hasn't been long enough know that breaking changes aren't introduced as often as I might have thought, yet 2016-2019 has been long enough to begin to doubt the constant "keep my local config file" routine. Thanks, again! It's all clear now.